# Extract array from multidimentional array wrt key

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
$users    = array();

$users[0]['id']=1;
$users[0]['name']="user1";

$users[1]['id']=2;
$users[1]['name']="user2";

$users[2]['id']=3;
$users[2]['name']="user3";
```

And i need to extract id's into another array $ids; such that

```
$ids[0]=1;
$ids[1]=2;
$ids[2]=3;
```

I know one way to do it...

```
$ids    = array();
foreach($users as $user){
   $ids[]  = $user['id'];
}
```

But

1.is it is the best way to doit?
 2.is it possible to do it without loops.
 3.is it is the fastest way....?

Comment: I don't think you can do this w/out loops. Your code looks just fine.

Comment: It is possible to do it with `array_walk()`/`array_map()` etc - but this is just a loop in a different coat and in this case I suspect it would be *less* efficient than your simple, effective and easy to read `foreach`. So in short `1.is it is the best way to doit?` - probably, yes. `2.is it possible to do it without loops.` - definitely not, no. Even things that don't look like loops are just loops underneath (in the C++ source). `3.is it is the fastest way....?` - again, probably yes. I'd be surprised if it wasn't. But with something that will take <10usec, speed is not really a concern.

Comment: 1. No,
2. No,
3. Probably,

Seriously, even if there is fastest way to do it I doubt it will make any difference in your overall code.

Comment: @IvanHušnjak `1. No` - care to expand? Or did you mean `Yes`?

Comment: @DaveRandom Oh sorry, you are right. I meant "yes, that is the best and simplest way to do it"

Comment: @DaveRandom; off course you can, see http://php.net/array_walk_recursive

Comment: @qeremy Yes but like I said `this is just a loop in a different coat and in this case I suspect it would be less efficient`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the comments above address the question very well, but since noone has actually posted any actual answer, here's some additional info (to justify my answering it):

- Is it the best way to do it?

Probably, but it is certainly the cleaner and most readable way to do it

- is it possible to do it without loops?

Yes, but as people have said, it's only a trick, as loops will be used in the background.

- is it is the fastest way?

Now this calls for some investigation. I have recreated a similar array as yours, using 100000 entries:

```
for ($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) {
    $users[] = array('id' => rand(),
            'name' => 'default');
}
```

And ran a few tests using different cases:

1.Plain old for loop (the one you have used yourself):

```
$ids=array();
$t = microtime(true);
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    $ids[] = $value['id'];
} 
echo microtime(true)-$t;
```

This required 0.085'' on average

2.Using array_walk():

```
$t = microtime(true);
array_walk($users, create_function('$v,$k,&$ids', '$ids[0][] = $v["id"];'), array(&$ids));
echo microtime(true)-$t;
```

This required on average 0.22'' (the same when using $GLOBALS['ids'] instead of this "reference" hack)

3.Using splFixedArray:
This iterator is supposed to be faster than plain arrays. Indeed, the code above requires 0.075'' on average:

```
$users = new SplFixedArray(100000);
for ($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) {
    $users[$i] = array('id' => rand(),
            'name' => 'default');
}
$ids=array();
$t = microtime(true);
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    $ids[$key] = $value['id'];
}
echo microtime(true)-$t;
```

While the code below, where we use splFixedArray for both arrays, performed even faster, around 0.062'':

```
$users = new SplFixedArray(100000);
for ($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) {
    $users[$i] = array('id' => rand(),
            'name' => 'default');
}
$ids=new SplFixedArray(100000);
$t = microtime(true);
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    $ids[$key] = $value['id'];
}
echo microtime(true)-$t;
```

So, the bottom line is that **no, it's not the fastest way, but it's the best if you take into account all 3 parameters you posed in your initial question**

Comment: +1: well said, although `array_map` is probably more appropriate than `array_walk` here. Shouldn't alter the performance numbers much though.

Comment: indeed, using array_map() is slightly better: it requires about 0.20'' on average

Comment: ok that's the answer;thanks to introducing me to SplFixedArray

Comment: Now in PHP 5.5 array_column does the job. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 0):

- I think the best way is your way as programmer (but if you in team then the best way is the team way).
- I think I'll go relying on built in PHP function (except some functions) for performance issues forever (cos I think the PHP peer work hard as needed to improve it).
- I think it's possible to do it without loops.

```
$users = array();
$users[0]['id'] = 100;
$users[1]['id'] = 101;
$users[2]['id'] = 102;

$ids = array();
array_walk_recursive($users, function($val, $key) use(&$ids){
    if ($key == 'id') $ids[] = $val;
});

print_r($ids);


Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 101
    [2] => 102
)
```